# SQL - Calculate cumulative average cost price for a product

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-structures, view

I was wondering if anyone could at least point me in the right direction with this issue.

I need to calculate the average cost of inventory but the caveat being that it should only be calculated on the latest procurement of products, relating to what we have in stock.

To try and explain in a better fashion, product x, we have purchased in total 1,200 units from various suppliers at different costs.  We only have 150 units left in stock so, to get the average purchase price and value of the remaining items, we would need to get the average cost of the products from the latest 150 units purchased **only**.

I have a view which produces the following:

```
 ProductId (int) - PK
 ProductName (varchar(150))
 StockInHand (int)
```

The related tables are as follows (truncated for ease of use)

**PurchaseOrder**

```
PurchaseOrderId (int) - PK
PurchaseOrderDate (DateTime)
PurchaseOrderStatus (int) - FK
```

Purchase order status - 1 = Open, 2 = Checked In

**PurchaseOrderLine**

```
PurchaseOrderLineId (int) - PK 
Qty (int)
UnitPrice (decimal(18,2))
ProductId (int) - FK
PurchaseOrderId (int) - FK
```

**UPDATE**

I have created an sql-fiddle here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/69288/1

You will see that I have three purchase orders of goods:

1: Qty 20 @ £40ea
2: Qty 20 @ £30ea
3: Qty 10 @ £25ea

I have two orders of the same goods:

1: Qty 10
2: Qty 15

From this, I can get the stock on hand: **25**

I need the average purchase price of the stock I have left.

I have 25 units left so I need to work backwards from the latest purchase orders to get the value.

I will take 10 from purchase order 3 and 15 from purchase order 2:

10 * £25 = £250
15 * £30 = £450

£700 / 25 = £28

I hope this makes my problem clearer!

Thank you

**UPDATE 2**

Thank you very much, Sticky Bit for taking the time out to post a solution to my problem and for explaining it so thoughtfully.

I have tried this on my dev DB and seem to have a problem.

I have 4 purchase orders for the same product (with two placed on the same day)

I have not worked out how to format tables gracefully in this text editor so please bear with me:

**PurchaseOrderId** / **PurchaseOrderDate**
2 / 2018-07-28
3 / 2018-07-29
4 / 2018-07-30
5 / 2018-07-30

I have the following PurchaseOrderLine

**PurchaseOrderLineId** / **PurchaseOrderId** / **ProductId** / **Qty** /  **UnitPrice**
3 / 2 / 8 / 20 / 400.00
4 / 3 / 8 / 40 / 420.00
5 / 4 / 8 / 25 / 500.00
6 / 5 / 8 / 1 / 200.00

Running the following:

```
SELECT pol.productid,
   po.purchaseorderdate,
   sum(pol.qty) qty,
   avg(pol.unitprice) unitprice
   FROM purchaseorder po
        INNER JOIN purchaseorderline pol
                   ON pol.purchaseorderid = po.purchaseorderid
   GROUP BY pol.productid,
            po.purchaseorderdate;
```

Gives me these results:

8   2018-07-28 00:00:00.000 20  400.000000
8   2018-07-29 00:00:00.000 40  420.000000
8   2018-07-30 00:00:00.000 26  350.000000

You will note that the average cost for the products purchased on 30th July is off (it is taking the average between the two prices and not taking the qty into account - I'm not sure if this is by design?)

If I then run the following:

```
SELECT po.productid,
   po.purchaseorderdate,
   sum(po.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY po.productid
                     ORDER BY po.purchaseorderdate) qty,
   sum(po.unitprice) OVER (PARTITION BY po.productid
                           ORDER BY po.purchaseorderdate) unitprice
   FROM (SELECT pol.productid,
                po.purchaseorderdate,
                sum(pol.qty) qty,
                avg(pol.unitprice) unitprice
                FROM purchaseorder po
                     INNER JOIN purchaseorderline pol
                                ON pol.purchaseorderid = po.purchaseorderid
                GROUP BY pol.productid,
                         po.purchaseorderdate) po;
```

I get the following results:

8   2018-07-28 00:00:00.000 20  400.000000
8   2018-07-29 00:00:00.000 60  820.000000
8   2018-07-30 00:00:00.000 86  1170.000000

Again, something seems to be amiss here with regards to the unitprice.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Kind regards

Comment: sample data (and possibly a sample schema on [sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) would help in creating an answer for this question, because at the moment its difficult to see what the problem is the only links to quantity and price live on the same table

Comment: Hi WTP, I have created a sql-fiddle and have updated my original post accordingly.

Comment: So what is the `unitprice` then? I figured it was the price per piece, so the total price for a a line would be `unitprice * qty`. Is this assumption wrong and the `unitprice` is the price for the whole batch, i.e. the price for an individual item is `unitprice / qty`? And what do you want to have in the end, the average price per piece or that price multiplied with the number of stocked items?

Comment: Hi Sticky Bit, no, you are correct. The unitprice is the price per item.

I need the average cost price of an item, relating to the amount we have left in stock.

For example, using my updated info above, if we have 30 items left in stock, the average cost price would work out to be £466:

(1 x 200 = £200) + (25 x 500 = £12,500) + (4 x 420 = £1,280) / 30

I apologise if this is getting a little confusing.

Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First we need to find a query to give us the current stock level for each product. For that, we left join `purchaseorderline` and `orderline` to `product` and calculate the differences for each row. Since a product can be in multiple orders we additionally aggregate the result, to get the overall difference -- the current stock level -- for each product.

   ```
   SELECT p.productid,
          p.productname,
          sum(coalesce(pol.qty, 0) - coalesce(ol.qty, 0)) qty
          FROM product p
               LEFT JOIN purchaseorderline pol
                         ON pol.productid = p.productid
               LEFT JOIN orderline ol
                         ON ol.productid = p.productid
          GROUP BY p.productid,
                   p.productname;
   ```
2. Next we need the quantity, that was stocked for each product and day (of `purchaseorders`). To get that, we inner join `purchaseorder` and `purchaseorderline`. Again we aggregate to account for the possible case, that multiple orders on the same day were made for the same product.

   ```
   SELECT pol.productid,
          po.purchaseorderdate,
          sum(pol.qty) qty,
          sum(pol.qty * pol.unitprice) unitprice
          FROM purchaseorder po
               INNER JOIN purchaseorderline pol
                          ON pol.purchaseorderid = po.purchaseorderid
          GROUP BY pol.productid,
                   po.purchaseorderdate;
   ```

   We can now use the previous result and window functions to get the sum of the quantity stocked and the average price of the products up to each day.

   ```
   SELECT po.productid,
          po.purchaseorderdate,
          sum(po.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY po.productid
                            ORDER BY po.purchaseorderdate) qty,
          sum(po.unitprice) OVER (PARTITION BY po.productid
                                  ORDER BY po.purchaseorderdate)
          /
          sum(po.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY po.productid
                            ORDER BY po.purchaseorderdate) unitprice
          FROM (SELECT pol.productid,
                       po.purchaseorderdate,
                       sum(pol.qty) qty,
                       sum(pol.qty * pol.unitprice) unitprice
                       FROM purchaseorder po
                            INNER JOIN purchaseorderline pol
                                       ON pol.purchaseorderid = po.purchaseorderid
                       GROUP BY pol.productid,
                                po.purchaseorderdate) po;
   ```

Now we put the results from 1. and 2. together using `OUTER APPLY`. For each product, we select the `TOP 1` result from 2. ordered by the day descending -- i.e. younger orders first --, that stocked a quantity greater than or equal to the one currently in stock.

```
SELECT p.productid,
       p.productname,
       po.unitprice
       FROM (SELECT p.productid,
                    p.productname,
                    sum(coalesce(pol.qty, 0) - coalesce(ol.qty, 0)) qty
                    FROM product p
                         LEFT JOIN purchaseorderline pol
                                   ON pol.productid = p.productid
                         LEFT JOIN orderline ol
                                   ON ol.productid = p.productid
                    GROUP BY p.productid,
                             p.productname) p
            OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
                                po.unitprice
                                FROM (SELECT po.productid,
                                             po.purchaseorderdate,
                                             sum(po.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY po.productid
                                                               ORDER BY po.purchaseorderdate) qty,
                                             sum(po.unitprice) OVER (PARTITION BY po.productid
                                                                     ORDER BY po.purchaseorderdate)
                                             /
                                             sum(po.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY po.productid
                                                               ORDER BY po.purchaseorderdate) unitprice
                                             FROM (SELECT pol.productid,
                                                          po.purchaseorderdate,
                                                          sum(pol.qty) qty,
                                                          sum(pol.qty * pol.unitprice) unitprice
                                                          FROM purchaseorder po
                                                               INNER JOIN purchaseorderline pol
                                                                          ON pol.purchaseorderid = po.purchaseorderid
                                                          GROUP BY pol.productid,
                                                                   po.purchaseorderdate) po) po
                                WHERE po.productid = p.productid
                                      AND po.qty >= p.qty
                                ORDER BY po.purchaseorderdate DESC) po;
```

Comment: Dear Sticky Bit, thank you so much for taking the time out to help me with this.  It is greatly appreciated. I have updated my post to show the issues I am getting with your solution. Thank you again

Comment: @GrantS: I edited my answer. I hope I got it right this time? If not, I'd suggest you maybe add a more comprehensive dataset (to your fiddle) and the (partial) result(s), that are right for it.

Comment: Dear Sticky Bit, this looks like it works perfectly with regards to the calculation of the average price.  Thank you so much for this.  The only problem is that the final result shows a list of all my products with the same "unitprice". I only have purchase records for one product so should these values be 'null' instead? Thank you again

Comment: Dear Sticky Bit,

I added the following:  WHERE po.qty >= p.qty AND po.ProductId = p.ProductId which seems to make it work perfectly!  One more thing, however. I have a ProductVariation table with ProductId, VariationName. Products can have zero or more variations and I need to work this in with the solution you have provided.  Should I mark this as a solution and create a more structured question? I thought I could extrapolate the solution myself but I am having trouble with it. Kind regards,

Comment: @GrantS: You're right, I forgot to link the `productid`. I corrected this.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sticky Bit. I have a ProductVariationId on both the PO and Order.  A product can have zero or more variations.  To achieve the result, I have simply doubled up on your solution in a view. One to take into account products without a ProductVariationId and one for products with a ProductVariationId. Is this an expensive way of achieving it?
Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see 'UnitCost,' so I'm going to use 'UnitPrice' as the cost in my code example.

I don't know that this is perfect, but it may help you in the right direction.

```
SELECT (SUM(UnitPrice)/150) FROM OrderDetails
WHERE PurchaseOrderId IS BETWEEN 1050 AND 1200
GO
```

Comment: HI Jonah, many thanks for taking the time to reply. Your solution isn't really what I am looking for. I have updated my original post to better explain my problem. Thanks again.